# Subnet With Two IPv6 Routers / How To Get Default Route Correct?

Tags: networking, router, routing, ipv6

I am trying to create a subnet with two IPv6 routers, call them R1 and R2. Originally, my subnet had only R1, connecting it to the Internet via a Hurricane Electric tunnel. R1 was (and still is) running radvd, and all hosts on the subnet are working fine (and still are, so I won't post R1's radvd.conf here). Recently, I added R2 to the subnet, and put another (new) subnet behind it. I have radvd running on R2, with the following radvd.conf file:

```
interface eth2 {
  AdvSendAdvert on;
  MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
  MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
  prefix 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 {
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
  };
};
interface eth0 {
  AdvSendAdvert on;
  MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
  MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
  prefix 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 {
    AdvAutonomous off;
    AdvOnLink off;
  };
  route 2001:470:291c:0002::/64 {};
};
```

Where eth0 is connected to the original subnet, and eth2 is connected to the new subnet.

**Here's the problem**: The RAs from R2 are overriding the default route on all the hosts on the original subnet (so that they no longer have the correct default route, as advertised by R1). R2's default route still correctly points at R1, so everything on the subnet "works", in that external IPv6 nodes are reachable, but all external traffic is now incorrectly getting routed through R2.

**So my question is**: how can I prevent the RAs from R2 from setting the default route for hosts on my original subnet (the one with both R1 and R2 connected to it)? I need the RAs from R1 to provide that default route!

Many thanks, in advance.

Comment: Why are you sending router advertisements on eth0 at all? What do you want to achieve if not letting itself as a default gateway? You can turn of the advertising of a default gateway by setting the lifetime on that interface to zero, but if there is no other purpose then don't send router advertisements at all...

Comment: Please don't xxx out more information than truly necessary. If you can, draw a diagram of your network, with the routers and their interfaces marked.

Comment: And not related to your question, but your advertisement intervals are extremely short. I have seen a Nest thermostat getting so hot that it would mis-measure the room temperature because of such settings. They are also really bad for the battery life of any wireless devices on your networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to not send router advertisements at all on eth0:

```
interface eth0 {
    AdvSendAdvert off;
}
```

If there are other reasons that you want to send router advertisements then explicitly tell receivers that the router is not a default gateway:

```
interface eth0 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    AdvDefaultLifetime 0;
}
```

From the `radvd.conf` manual:

> A lifetime of 0 indicates that the router is not a default router and should not appear on the default router list.

Comment: Thanks very much. The reason that I want to send RAs out eth0 is that I want hosts on my 'original' subnet to be able to reach hosts on my 'new' subnet. I look forward to seeing how that `AdvDefaultLifetime 0;` changes the RA (time to break out wireshark!).

Comment: In that case set the `AdvDefaultLifetime` to 0 to signal it is not a default gateway, and add a `route` option to signal it is a gateway for that specific route. You don't need to advertise the `prefix` option on eth0 of R2 because R1 will already do that. Also make sure that R1 has a (static) route to R2 for the subnet behind it. Clients that don't understand the route option will use R1 as default gateway, and then R1 needs to know where to send those packets.

Comment: thanks for your help. This is very good guidance, and I appreciate the time you took to help.

Answer (score 0):

Both Ethernets have the same "prefix 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64"?

- If so, that looks very wrong.
- If not, it would be best to have specified 2001:db8:yyyy:yyyy" so it looks different

  - 2001:db8 is good for examples.  Some other valid addresses may use 2001

As my memory serves me, I believe I've worked more with BSD rtadvd than Linux's radvd - same concepts, a bit of a different implementation.

However, I offer this advice: Can you start radvd to listen on only one interface, and specify a configuration file?  Also, can you do that a second time, listening only on another interface, and specifying another configuration file?  If so, that may reduce your chances of certain behaviors seeming to leak to another interface.

Do you really want AdvSendAdvert "on" for both subnets (on Router 2)?

Hardware could also cause this, if cabling allows another connection between the subnets.